# Downlodify is not working, no error message at all

Tags: javascript, downloadify

I have the latest shock wave (11.9.900.117) add-on installed to my Firefox (24).

When i download and run the sample test.html file nothing is happening.But when i run the same demo linked (http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html) HTML from Git hub works as expected.

Also i have tried this with my project too, same kind of output, nothing happens but the button hides.There are no error messages shown or can be caught since i cant go through the swfobject.js file.

I am using javascript alone, not jquery etc.

Is there anything that i am missing some basic stuffs?

Also asked in https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify/issues/34.
Any simple working examples would be helpfull.!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not going to dig any deeper as to how it's coded but it would appear to be falling victim to the stricter [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) on the [`file://`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs) system.  It may not interact with a server but it still needs to be served from one (unless you disable certain security settings in your browser).

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to use it at the `file://` protocol as ell - but if not, please add more to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is old, but for anyone who encounters the same problem, here is how I solved it.

If you want to run Downlodify from the local filesystem you need to edit the Flash Player Global Security Settings and add the Downlodify folder as a trusted location.

Currently the settings can be edited [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html). The location URI looks like this file:///C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Downloadify-master